# How to style the background of the bullet points in a <ul>?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with this CSS:

```
.list-item > * {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.multi-line-content {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

which produces output that looks like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/b8rxwzgz/)):

[image: unstyled UL output]

I need to style the background where the list bullets are, such that it would look something like this:

[image: styled UL output]

I've tried setting a border on the UL, but this extends to the bottom of the whole list (including the "multi-line content" divs), which is not the desired look.  The background should not extend below the bottom of the last "Label" line.  I am looking for suggestions for CSS tricks to make this work, or alternative CSS/HTML structures that would produce the same output.  The solution should work for any number of `<li>` elements, and ideally be pure CSS/HTML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that doesn't require changes to your markup or height statements.

```css
.list-item > * {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.multi-line-content {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  border-left: 12px solid;
}
li:last-child {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 12px;
}
li > span {
  border-left: 12px solid;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list-item"> <span>Label</span>

    <div class="multi-line-content">multi-
      <br />line
      <br />content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item"> <span>Label</span>

    <div class="multi-line-content">multi-
      <br />line
      <br />content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item"> <span>Label</span>

    <div class="multi-line-content">multi-
      <br />line
      <br />content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
.list-item {
    border-left: 10px solid black;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

ul li:last-child{
   height: 15px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8rxwzgz/5/)

[image]

Comment: Not bad! Certainly simpler than my attempt. I wonder how cross-browser compatible it is with the overflow.

Comment: Nice idea, but it breaks when you have other content below the list (the multi-line content div overlaps whatever is below the list).

Comment: You could probably wrap the list in a div with `overflow: hidden` to remedy that.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the look you're after. You'll need to check it works in key browsers your users will have.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}

.list-item  {
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: white;
}
.multi-line-content {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add another div in your `li` and work with it like this:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <div class="a">
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
        </li></div>

    <div class="a">
    <li class="list-item">
        <span>Label</span>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
        </li></div>

    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="b">
        <span>Label</span></div>
        <div class="multi-line-content">
            multi-<br />
            line<br />
            content
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list-item > * {
    vertical-align: top;

}
.list-item{ list-style-type: none;}


.a{border-left:5px solid red;padding-left:7px;}
.b{border-left:5px solid red;padding-left:7px;display: inline;}

.multi-line-content {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, maybe you just want a fancier solution, but this works.I also have added some paragraphs after the list to check if this break the layout.

Have a look on this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/865r9Lah/)

Comment: Also if you want to have multi-line content, you should use the  `<p>` tag

Comment: This is invalid HTML. The only valid child of `ul` is `li`.